# How to clone a single branch in git when branch name and containing file name are same?

Tags: git

Currently I try to clone a specific single branch into a directory.

```
git clone -v --branch test --single-branch file:///git/abcef/ /tmp/sonar-scanner-20221/abcef/test/
```

So far, it works but I get following message:

> fatal: ambiguous argument 'test': both revision and filename Use '--'
>   to separate paths from revisions, like this: 'git 
>   [...] -- [...]'

So far it looks like git clones the right branch into the directory but I would feel better without that message. Problem here is, that the git root contains a file "test" which is the same name like the branch. Is there any option make it explicit that the given name is the branchname?

Edit: Sorry, found a problem in my script I was using and locate the problem on the wrong place

Comment: Try `git clone -v --branch test --single-branch file:///git/abcef/ -- /tmp/sonar-scanner-20221/abcef/test/`. There are spaces around `--` before `/tmp/`.

Comment: To add to Elpie's comment, `--` can be used to tell Git whether something is a branch or a filename.

Comment: Perhaps you could run with `GIT_TRACE` environment variable set to `1`? I cannot reproduce your error. What version of Git are you using and do you have anything special in your `.gitconfig`?